# Backwards compatibility of enum fields

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have an enum field with no default value:

```
{
  "name": "FavouriteIceCream",
  "type": "enum",
  "symbols": [
    "Vanilla",
    "Strawberry",
    "Chocolate"
  ]
}
```

The topic has compatibility mode set to BACKWARDS. If I remove one of the symbols, the Schema Registry API still reports the schema as compatible.

Is this correct? How would it parse a record with the field set to the now removed symbol?

Comment: What version of Confluent Schema Registry are you running? It might be a bug fixed by https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/1775

Answer (score 0):

Backward Compatibility
BACKWARD compatibility means that consumers using the new schema can read data produced with the last schema. For example, if there are three schemas for a subject that change in order X-2, X-1, and X then BACKWARD compatibility ensures that consumers using the new schema X can process data written by producers using schema X or X-1, but not necessarily X-2. If the consumer using the new schema needs to be able to process data written by all registered schemas, not just the last two schemas, then use BACKWARD_TRANSITIVE instead of BACKWARD. For example, if there are three schemas for a subject that change in order X-2, X-1, and X then BACKWARD_TRANSITIVE compatibility ensures that consumers using the new schema X can process data written by producers using schema X, X-1, or X-2.

BACKWARD: consumer using schema X can process data produced with schema X or X-1
BACKWARD_TRANSITIVE: consumer using schema X can process data produced with schema X, X-1, or X-2

An example of a backward compatible change is a removal of a field. A consumer that was developed to process events without this field will be able to process events written with the old schema and contain the field – `the consumer will just ignore that field.`

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html

Comment: Thanks but those docs refer to removing a field. 
I'm asking about removing a symbol from an enum field.

Answer (score 0):

The [Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution) states:

> if the writer's symbol is not present in the reader's enum and the reader has a default value, then that value is used, otherwise an error is signalled.

Your schema does not define a default value for the enum. If you remove one of the symbols, then the reader cannot parse a field set to the now removed symbol.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the registry should report it as incompatible in that case though?